# Secure Sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, secure-coding

Can one create a salt (random string), append it to a user id string, then md5 (or other encryption), save the same result as a cookie, and as a session variable, then include a php script on secure pages to make sure both cookie, and session variables match?

Would this be secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No more secure than letting PHP generate a session ID for you automatically, using the `session_start()` call.

It's still vulnerable to someone stealing your cookie with the session ID.

For better security, use HTTPS and mark the cookies as HTTP-only so javascript can't access them. You could also store the user's IP in a session variable and check that IP address matches the remote address of the user sending you back your cookie.